# How can I STOP the JSFL process in flash CS5?

Tags: jsfl

I write a JSFL script, have a very long loop, when this script is running, I can't stop it. only using the Alt-F4 to kill the Flash CS5, then restart it. this is too crazy. How can I stop the JSFL script without kill the Flash?

Comment: is't using Alt-F4, is using Task Manager to kill the Flash.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better approach: inside your loops, put a condition to check if a key was pressed. If the key was pressed, break the loop.

```
if(fl.tools.shiftIsDown)
{
    stopScript = true;
    return;
}
```

I used the "stopScript" var because I needed to break more then one loop to stop the script. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few advices:

- Optimize your script.
- Limit input
- Divide script logic into functional chunks that you can call them in a row every EnterFrame event. You can embed that script info WindowsSWF and use it's as EnterFrame event beacon (every frame WindowSWF panel calls a function in JSFL). You can add a button in a panel that stops calling JSFL function every frame.